# Debug chrome extension developed in ReactJS with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing an extension for chrome using ReactJs with TypeScript.

[image]

This is how my typescript code for extension. Now I am building this code and create source map using webpack like this

[image]

Now load the extension to the chrome browser. On click plugin icon its on popup. I inspect those popup for debug issues. so it's showing me like this

[image]

So here the source is missing.

[image]

These are the settings for the developer tool.

[image]

Here you can see that I am not getting the option to attach the source.

Without the source not able to debug the issue.
In a normal React app I can easily identify the .ts file put debug pointer over there and start to debug but in extension case, I am unable to do this.
Badly need this solution can anyone help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: You could always right-click popup.js in the developer console and use the "Add source map" option and give it a file url to the source map on disk.

Comment: Also make sure you have source maps enabled in the developer console settings.

Comment: @dwosk source map is enabled in developer mode, and I am not unable to attach my source code on popup.js

Comment: @dwosk.. I am editing the question with a screen shot of point that you mention, you can check with that

Comment: You need to right-click on the actual page that opens up in the middle of the console, not the filename in the sidebar.

Comment: @dwok, found the option for the source map and I am giving the absolute path for that and try with multiple options and unable to attach it. even that if something goes wrong to attach they don't give any error message on that

Comment: make sure it's a file url not just an absolute path

Comment: @dwosk, can you guide me on how to give file url while this code in local development

Comment: open your source map in chrome. Open With > Chrome. Then copy/paste the address in the url bar. It should be something like file:///<path to your file>